# How do you include OpenCV into a javascript project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, opencv, npm

I recently installed OpenCV through npm using the following guide:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv

My question is pretty simple. How do I actually use the OpenCV library in my project?

On that site, there is a face detection example that looks like this:

```
cv.readImage("./examples/files/mona.png", function(err, im){
  im.detectObject(cv.FACE_CASCADE, {}, function(err, faces){
    for (var i=0;i<faces.length; i++){
      var x = faces[i]
      im.ellipse(x.x + x.width/2, x.y + x.height/2, x.width/2, x.height/2);
    }
    im.save('./out.jpg');
  });
})
```

The `cv.` variable is where I'm stuck at. Typically whenever I install a new package using npm, I would add it to my `app.js` file like so:

```
angular
  .module('App', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.sortable',
    'firebase',
    'angular-toArrayFilter'
  ])
```

Similarly in any of my controllers, I would add the name of the module as a parameter to the controller:

```
angular.module('App')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, UserAuth, $window, $firebaseArray, fireBaseRef)
```

I can't seem to find the dependency name for OpenCV to even allow me to use it in the first place. None of the guides that I've looked at to date ever mention how to include it into your project.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: OpenCV is probably a library like Lodash where it just has this cv variable attached to the window object. You can wrap it in your own service or just globally call cv.someFunction and it should work fine.

Comment: I've tried doing this, but I just get an error saying that cv is not defined.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure if you did this but it seems that on the local computer that you intend to use this on you need OpenCV installed. If you want a true JS library for doing this https://trackingjs.com/ seems the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use OpenCV in browser-side javascript projects. OpenCV is a native library and `node-opencv` allows you to use it on the server, but you cannot use it directly in the browser.

From the [installation instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv) for `node-opencv`:

> You'll need OpenCV 2.3.1 or newer installed before installing
>   node-opencv. Note that OpenCV 3.x is not yet fully supported.

Comment: There is (somewhat confusingly) now [opencv-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@techstark/opencv-js) which works client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the installation instructions for whatever your operating system is (i.e. Mac OSX, Windows, Linux/Debian). Instructions for the most popular systems can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv.

Then, before using the 'cv' variable you must require the 'opencv' module.

```
var cv = require('opencv');
```

If you receive an error, it will usually be a dependency issue. Verify that you have correctly installed all the dependencies for node-opencv. On my first install I needed

```
npm install buffers
```

and

```
npm install node-pre-gyp
```

Depending on where you installed your opencv bundle, you  may need to explicitly include the file path to the opencv.js file like so

```
var cv = require('/path_to_node-opencv-master/lib/opencv');
```

I recommend reading the intro to OpenCV articles and the documentation on the OpenCV website at http://opencv.org/ to learn more.